# ClickOnce application accessing web service

Tags: c#, .net, clickonce

I have a ClickOnce application that is installed from the web, configured as a Full Trust application.  The application accesses a web service from a different host than the install URL.

If I understand [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8saf4wy(v=vs.100).aspx) correctly, the application should not be able to access the web service:

> Web Install: Can only access the Web server from which the application was installed.
>
> If your ClickOnce application cannot access a Web server because of security restrictions, the application must assert WebPermission for that Web site. For more information about increasing security permissions for a ClickOnce application, see Securing ClickOnce Applications.

I've been able to install the application on several machines with no issues.  Am I misinterpreting the statement above?  Or am I not running into this restriction for some other reason (such as my user account being in the admin group or something like that)?

Also, what does it mean to "assert WebPermission for that Web site". If there is a security restriction, does this allow my application to bypass it?

Comment: What is your webservice Binding Type?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the restrictions you quote on where a ClickOnce application can access data refers to data files. The next section refers to an XML Web Service.

I have several ClickOnce applications that call WCF services for information. They are in the same domain as the ClickOnce deployment, but not on the same server.

What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: My ClickOnce application is installed from www.somedomain.com, but it accesses a web service at a different domain someotherdomain.com.  As I've worked with this some more, it doesn't seem like the restriction I listed is applicable - my application runs fine most of the time.  I just came across this restriction while trying to troubleshoot the times when it has issues so was confused. FYI - your comments about clickonce here and on other sites have been extremely helpful as I've worked with it.

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad I've been able to help. I've done what you're talking about (accessing services on a differnet domain from a ClickOnce app), and it shouldn't matter. Once the ClickOnce application is installed, it has no other interaction with the deployment provider other than checking for updates. So this can't be your problem.